# Recursion - need to sum varibale but its'nt working

Tags: java, recursion

I want that sum is not reset each time, how is it possible?

The general idea of the code is I have a number of rabbits, each rabbit at number 3 has three ears each time the n comes from a number divisible by 3 then enters the sum 3, Otherwise enters the sum 2, in recursion.

The code:

```
public static int rabbit(int n){
    int sum=0;
    if(n%3==0)
    sum+=3;
    else if(n%3!=0)
        sum+=2;

    if(n==0)
        return sum; 
    return rabbit(n-1);

}
```

thank's

Comment: Either create a static field, or pass your variable as an argument to the recursive call.

Comment: Have you tried to use a debugger?

Comment: @shmosel there's a mistake in the code. No need for an additional field.

Comment: "each rabbit ... has 3 ears" ???

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your code is not using the `sum` unless `n` is zero.

The `return rabbit(n-1);` makes the recursive call, but forgets to factor the `sum` into the result.

You can fix this by adding `sum` to the value that you return:

```
return sum + rabbit(n-1);
```